# Git rm, gives scary "Deletion of directory failed" when I only delete one file

Tags: git

```
~/repo/samples>git rm subviews.js
rm 'samples/subviews.js'
Deletion of directory 'samples' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
```

Why does it try to delete directory when I clearly told that I want to delete the file?

To make it more clear:

*The same directory contains about 10 more files and they are also tracked by git.*

Comment: Is subviews.js the only file in samples directory?

Comment: no, there are 10 more

Comment: @exebook: Are those other files also tracked by git?

Comment: yes, they are also in repo for a month

Comment: For better diagnosis, what does `git status` say?

Comment: AFAIK each time a file is removed from a directory, git try to `unlink()` it regardless of its content. It's harmless (if you're not using an almost broken filesystem like sshfs http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.fuse.sshfs/1136 )

Answer (score 3):

Likely, the directory `samples` would be empty after the file removal. Git would normally delete it then, however since your shell's working directory is also in the same directory, removal fails.

Comment: Now that the original question has been edited to indicate that there are other files tracked by git in that directory, your answer is no longer correct.

Comment: Well, without further information, such as the output of `git status` or `git ls-tree` and `git ls-tree --other`, nobody will be able to help.

Comment: @MichaelWild you were down-voted because your answer is invalid to the actual issue (OP's directory still contains several tracked files). Git should not even be trying to rm the directory in the first place. The fact that it is failing is not the real issue.

Comment: @MichaelWild just letting you know why you were downvoted. Even though  they didn't mention it initially, it was the root of the problem. The issue will be resolved if git is updated to the latest stable version. (Edit: your answer should be downvoted because it doesn't offer a resolution to the actual issue, just an explanation which is misleading and uninformative, which may serve to confuse other users who have the same issue)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest version of msysgit.

I've had this for a long time with msysgit v1.7.11. After upgrading to v1.8.5 the problem disappeared.

Comment: This solution (upgrading) worked for me also.  Thank you @romkyns!